How to break the CSS styling from all rows inside ngFor?
I am building angular app, and I am using ngFor directive to create a table for the employees. for the employee's name, when I hover over it, I want this field to change its color (the hover over field only), I use(mouseenter) event binding to change the text color. the problem is when the mouse enters a specific employee name, all the employees names change their text color because of the ngFor directive instead of the specific field only, how can I solve it?
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
      <td (mouseenter)="applyColor=true" (mouseleave)="applyColor=false" 
[ngClass]="{'name-cell': applyColor}">{{ employee.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.department }}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


I tried to use inner span to include the styling but the same issue still exists.

The problem is that applyColor is a component-wide variable. When true, 'name-cell': applyColor === true will be true for each row. (I added === true for clarity).
If you want to keep your approach, save the index of the hovered element:
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees; index as i">
      <td (mouseenter)="hoveredIndex=i" (mouseleave)="hoveredIndex=null" 
[ngClass]="{'name-cell': hoveredIndex === i}">{{ employee.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.department }}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Where hoveredIndex is:
public hoveredIndex: number | null;


Only and advertisment, if we don't use strict equals (the three =) fall out because in javascript null==0. It's the reason I like more use hoveredIndex=-1 instead hoveredIndex=null when "mouseleave"

You could try a simpler approach, using only css hover.
In the component you just add a distinct class to the name cell (like: <td class='your-class'>{{ employee.name }}</td>and in the css you do your styling on .your-class:hover, no need for mouseenter and mouseleave.
Here's a working exemple on Stakblitz.

Christian Vincenzo Traina has offered the right and convenient solution to your problem. I just want to suggest a bit of refactoring using @for template syntax.
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @for (employee of employees; track $index; let i = $index) {
      <tr>
        <td 
          (mouseenter)="hoveredIndex = i 
          (mouseleave)="hoveredIndex = null"
          [class.name-cell]="hoveredIndex === i"
        >
          {{ employee.name }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ employee.department }}</td>
        <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>


We use @for instead ngFor that is much more intuitive.
We use class binding to create a single class binding which more readable and cleaner than ngClass when we need a single binding.

docs - https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow#for-block---repeaters
